# Correct design of aggregate roots

Tags: domain-driven-design

Somewhere far, far away in a domain galaxy there is mention of

- 'Measurement values' and 'Places'
- Each 'Measurement value' comes from/belongs to a specific 'Place'
- Each 'Measurement value' is registered on a given date & time and of a given, specific type (eg. waterflow, wind, etc)
- Each 'Place' has a name and a collection of 'Measurement Values' that gets registered

Given my current model where 'Places' are the aggregate root that holds 'Measurement values' I have a dilemma:

Users wishes to view one type of measurement values at a time and there are quite a lot of measurement values.
To load all measurement values when only some of them are needed seems unneccessary..

Eg. Im stuck on how to organize/model the need "Show me waterflows (measurement values) in River X (Place) between time A and B"

Is it allowed to instantiate River X aggregate root only partially loaded with the type of measurement values concerned in a given use case?
Are there other ways of modelling measurement values and their origin?

Please let med know your thoughts...

Comment: Maybe [my post](http://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2014/10/31/DDD-Identifying-Bounded-Contexts-and-Aggregates-Entities-and-Value-Objects.aspx/) will help you . Also CQRS is almost a golden hammer for DDD.  About loading partial aggregates it's a no, it defeats the purpose of an aggregate root.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback MikeSW :-) I'm pondering the idea of making place a valueobject that each Measurement value contains..

Comment: @oakman Is that only a problem on the read side of things or also when you want to modify something ? Do you have a lot of concurrency on the `Place` aggregate ?

Comment: guillaume31, no there is not so much concurrency on "Place"..

Answer (score 1):

I think that your aggregate is consistent as it is. Your dilemma as nothing to do with domain model but rather than with a presentation model.

I will consider the possibility to deserialize each measurement in a NoSQL instance, in this way your presenteation layer could filter and make any query without affecting the consistency of domain layer.

Comment: thanks for your feedback marianoc84, do you mean that I should render a "SaveValue4Presentation" event when it is accuired?

Comment: No, you should raise event for any business related events. `SaveValue4Presentation` is not business (but a technical issue). You should raise a `NewMeasurementAddedEvent`. Somewhere else you have an event handler for aforementioned event. At this point you can deserialize in the way you thing's appropriated. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it sounds very much like the data model and storage are impacting the design of your system? If this is so it may be the cause of your dilemma. A key part of the benefit modeling using aggregates is it is free of dependencies. Dependencies such as databases and data models. There is no direct 'view' of an aggregate, so it's not shaped by the view. This makes aggregates much easier to design. They are much more focused on solving the problem. And are therefore great candidates for doing complex stuff.

If it turns out you don't need aggregates to model your domain. You can then just focus on an efficient storage and retrieval mechanism.

In other words...

Don't tie yourself up in knots doing DDD if you don't need to.

If it helps I created an infographic on common DDD mistakes. You may find it helpful. You can find it [here](http://danielwhittaker.me/2015/07/05/are-you-making-these-10-ddd-mistakes/).

By the way, I think DDD is a great way to go, but only if your domain warrants it. Appologies if I have misunderstood you.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Codescribler :-)

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see the real problem. You said that each `Measurement` is tied to a specific `Place`, then you don't have to load all `Measurements`.

Using correct data layer configuration, you can load the required `Measurement` by selecting/loading/instantiating only it's parent (`Place`).